github webhook triggers jenkins job only on merge request
We have github webhook with events pull request and push checked .
Using this to trigger jenkins job(pipeline job) for pull request open and update , however its not working as expected.
Only merge request to main branch triggers Jenkins job .
webhook event check
I need to run jenkins pipeline job for every pull request in github repository and the jenkins plugin -github pull request builder
this plugin have errors  and its configuration in jenkins not working with secret text.
Expected - trigger jenmins job when github Pull request opened, updated and get the status of jenkins job as github check to pull request.
Please do suggest me any alternative?

Webhooks only trigger when a change of state occurs. If you have existing pull requests when you create the webhook, nothing will trigger until the state changes, such as when a merge occurs. If you create a new pull request after you set up the webhook, it should trigger.

Even for new Pull request job is not getting triggered.

Does your Jenkins user have permission to access the non-main branches? Are the non-main branches being scanned?

how to check that ?

I don't use any fancy plugins. I use the multibranch pipeline (Jenkins Dashboard, then New item). Once it is set up, there are options to "Scan Multibranch Pipeline Now" then click "Scan Multibranch Pipeline Log" to see what branches were found. If your branch is not found at all, check your discover branch filters in Jenkins Multibranch pipeline configuration and check security settings in your git repo.
